# WebView Woocommerce Cart Page

Tags: android, woocommerce, webview, cart

I am creating a simple android app to navigate through my Woocommerce store (using android webview for that).

Problem is when I reach cart page -> page loads correctly at first but when i click on update quantity or delete a product from the cart, page goes blank.

I really do not know what is the solution to this issue.

I guess that I should buy an already made android app to do this.

I am using Android Studio 3.

Is there anyone who have had this issue before?

Thank you.

Comment: i think this is going to be pretty hard to tell you what the error is without looking at code. I think it might be better the develop an app specific on android and then create an API to hit your website.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach webview to chrome debugger console and check what exactly is happening there. Although it's very difficult to debug for here but surely you will get help from chrome debugger.

If you can attach some screenshots of woocommerce website that might be helpful.

Thanks